# Unity 3D Slow car (wheel colliders)

Tags: unity, physics

My car is moving very slowly even though I apply high amounts of torque to the wheel colliders. The only thing I found to be helpful was to increase the wheel's friction stiffness, but that really messes up the braking and makes the car shake.

The values I use for setting up the car and torque are realistic (1500 kg car, 20 kg wheels, a realistic torque value accounting for gear ratios etc.), so I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your wheels are slipping. You can check that using rpm attribute from wheel collider component and compare with the rpms of a real life wheel with same specs(radius, current speed of car), you can use https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/6-1-rotation-angle-and-angular-velocity or search by yourself, and use velocity vector of the rigidbody(transform to local and get .z component) to get velocity of car in game. If you have considerable much more rpms or less in unity this means that is slipping, respective skidding, so you lose traction. In this case you have to change forward friction values until the values are similar. Sideways friction is used only for turns, but maybe this have to be change too for smooth movements.

A little difference have to exists, from that difference you have the traction force, this difference is **slip** from curve graphic from the manual.
The slip is difference between angular velocity of wheel and linear velocity of car. If slip is too big you will get the asymtote value. So you have to get the corect forces to move the rigidbody with optim slip.

Wheels colliders are very tricky and working with try and error for many of us.